# $\operatorname{supp}(M) \subseteq \operatorname{supp}(N) \iff f_I(M)\subseteq f_I(N) $?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, local-cohomology

Let $ R $ be a commutative unital ring, $ I $ an ideal of $ R $, and $ M $ an $ R $-module. It has proven ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/793581/the-relationship-between-cohomological-dimension-and-support)) that if $\operatorname{supp}(M) \subseteq \operatorname{supp}(N)$ then 
$\operatorname{cd}(I,M) \leq \operatorname{cd}(I,N)$. From this fact  one guesses that there is a relationship between "$f_I(-)$, the *finiteness dimension* of modules relative to $I$", and "the support of modules" such as: $$\operatorname{supp}(M) \subseteq \operatorname{supp}(N) \iff f_I(M)\le  f_I(N).  $$

> Can anyone prove this relationship or give a counterexample, please? You can add any assumption that helps, such as "being local", or prove it for equality.

$f_I(M) = \inf\ \{i  : H_I^i(M)$ is not finitely generated$\}$ is defined in chapter 9 of the book *Local Cohomology. An Algebraic Introduction with Geometric Applications* by *M. P. BRODMANN* and *R. Y. SHARP*.